# Define a javascript variable under conditions with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like the title says, I would like to fill a variable up under some conditions

I thought I could do like that but no :

```
var content = $(function() {
    if ($('#content').length) {
        return  $('#content');
    }

    if ($('#content_no_decoration').length) {
        return  $('#contenu_no_decoration');
    }

    if ($('#full_content').length) {
        return  $('#full_content');
    }

    if ($('#full_content_no_decoration').length) {
        return  $('#full_content_no_decoration');
    }
});
```

So I thought that the javascript variable 'content' would be one of the jquery object representing an element in the dom. But it seems that 'content' is the function.

I guess you imagine what i want to do.. What is the syntax with JQuery ?

Thank you

Comment: jQuery doesn't introduce new *syntax*.  It's just JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only declaring the function, so `content` contains a pointer to the function.

Execute it and you are fine:

```
var content = function() {
    if ($('#content').length) {
        return  $('#content');
    }

    if ($('#content_no_decoration').length) {
        return  $('#contenu_no_decoration');
    }

    if ($('#full_content').length) {
        return  $('#full_content');
    }

    if ($('#full_content_no_decoration').length) {
        return  $('#full_content_no_decoration');
    }
}();
```

But you don't really need a function here. If the script tag is at the bottom of the page (right before the closing `</body>`-tag), or the assignment is within a load handler you could use:

```
var content = $('#content').length 
               ? $('#content') 
               : $('#content_no_decoration').length 
                 ? $('#content_no_decoration')
                 : $('#full_content').length 
                   ? $('#full_content')
                   : $('#full_content_no_decoration').length 
                     ? $('#full_content_no_decoration')
                     : undefined;
```

Or use jQuery to your advantage and keep things really short:

```
var content = 
  $('#content,#content_no_decoration,#full_content,#full_content_no_decoration')
   .get(0);
// if none of the elements exist, content will be undefined, otherwise
// it will contain [a JQuery Object of] the first existing element
```

Comment: I think OP wants to wait until the DOM is ready to do this, otherwise these jQuery selectors will all come back as empty (assuming the script is at the top of his page).

Comment: second part : it is great thank you.. exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Hi @mlwacosmos, glad I could help. I added a shorter assignment to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`$(function() {  })` is short-code for the DOMReady event. You need to explicitly define a function, and then assign the return value to your variable.

For example:

```
function getObj() 
{
    if($('#content').length) 
    {
        return  $('#content');
    }

    if($('#content_no_decoration').length) 
    {
        return  $('#contenu_no_decoration');
    }

    if($('#full_content').length) 
    {
        return  $('#full_content');
    }

    if($('#full_content_no_decoration').length) 
    {
        return  $('#full_content_no_decoration');
    }
}
```

You can then assign the value as :

```
var content = getObj();
```

You will need to call the assignment when the DOM is ready though, otherwise the selectors will not trigger as expected. For example:

```
$(function() {  
    var content = getObj();
});
```

Comment: I think OP wants to wait until the DOM is ready to do this, otherwise these jQuery selectors will all come back as empty (assuming the script is at the top of his page).

Comment: He only needs to add the assignment inside `$(function() { });`. Anyway, updated with this instruction, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

why you don't do like that ?

```
function thatsAGoodName() {
    if ($('#content').length) {
        return  $('#content');
    }

    if ($('#content_no_decoration').length) {
        return  $('#contenu_no_decoration');
    }

    if ($('#full_content').length) {
        return  $('#full_content');
    }

    if ($('#full_content_no_decoration').length) {
        return  $('#full_content_no_decoration');
    }
}
var content = thatsAGoodName();
```

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
$(function() {
    // DOM safe to use do stuff
})
```

Is shorthand for the document ready event. This tells you the coder that the dom is safe to use.

You would not really return anything from this event.

Answer (score 0):

`content` is an object because you're setting it to a object here:

```
var content = $(function() {
```

What you  probably intended was:

```
var content;

if ($('#content').length) {
    content = $('#content');
}

if ($('#content_no_decoration').length) {
    content = $('#contenu_no_decoration'); // Is #contenu a typo???
}

if ($('#full_content').length) {
    content = $('#full_content');
}

if ($('#full_content_no_decoration').length) {
    content = $('#full_content_no_decoration');
}
```

Note, that this will have a reference to an element now. If you want the actual content you'll need to pull it out with something like [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Actually, `content` isn't a function. It's a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange it a little bit and it should work:

```
$(function () {
    var content = (function() {
        var regularContent = $('#content');
        if (regularContent.length !== 0) {
            return regularContent;
        }

        var contentNoDecoration = $('#content_no_decoration');
        if (contentNoDecoration.length !== 0) {
            return contentNoDecoration;
        }

        var fullContent = $('#full_content');
        if (fullContent.length !== 0) {
            return fullContent;
        }

        var fullContentNoDecoration = $('#full_content_no_decoration');
        if (fullContentNoDecoration.length !== 0) {
            return fullContentNoDecoration;
        }
    }());
});
```

This code is basically saying once the DOM is ready (the `$(function () { ... });` part), run this anonymous function (the `(function () { ... }());` part) and assign its return value to `content`.

Edit: Also, you're losing efficiency by running each of your selectors twice instead of just once.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the shorthand for the jQuery ready event (`$(function() {`. What I believe you want is a self invoking function:

```
// remove the call to jQuery 
var content = (function() {
   if ($('#content').length) {
        return  $('#content');
    }
   // ... more
})(); // invoke the function, which should return a jQuery object
```

You may need to wrap this in a document.ready, depending on where your script is executed.

Answer (score -1):

It's true that content is the function, but you can use that function. Like:

```
var result = content();
```

#### Edit:

Remove the `$()` around `var content = $({/* code */})` and it works.

Comment: Obviously, with or without the $, I cannot do that

Comment: Without `$()` you can. I was wrong with about that it works with.